# Tizen IDE crashes all the time

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Tizen IDE crashes all the time when I want to start example project. I'm running Tizen IDE 1.0.0b2 under Ubuntu 12.04.

Currently it gives me following ouput. It seems that the problem is here:

err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\windows\system32\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)
Though, I've no idea why IDE try to access windows libraries.

Output form IDE:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:PermSize=128M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-XX:MaxNewSize=128M
-XX:NewSize=128M
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-Dlog4j.configuratorClass=org.tizen.common.util.log.TizenLog4jConfigurator
-jar /home/satybald/tizen-wearable-sdk2/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/satybald/tizen-wearable-sdk2/ide/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/satybald/tizen-wearable-sdk2/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so
-startup /home/satybald/tizen-wearable-sdk2/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 12800d
-nl en
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:PermSize=128M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-XX:MaxNewSize=128M
-XX:NewSize=128M
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-Dlog4j.configuratorClass=org.tizen.common.util.log.TizenLog4jConfigurator
-jar /home/satybald/tizen-wearable-sdk2/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```

Output from console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.tizen.common.core.application.InstallPathConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

(Tizen IDE for Wearable:8084): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Tizen IDE for Wearable:8084): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Tizen IDE for Wearable:8084): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Tizen IDE for Wearable:8084): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Tizen IDE for Wearable:8084): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_1_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.1.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/satybald/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] using wine prefix directory /home/satybald/.wine-pipelight.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[install-dependency] wine-silverlight5.1-installer is already installed in '/home/satybald/.wine-pipelight'.
[install-dependency] wine-mpg2splt-installer is already installed in '/home/satybald/.wine-pipelight'.
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe"
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] embedded mode         is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] windowless mode       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] linux windowless mode is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] force SetWindow       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] window class hook     is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] strict draw ordering  is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function CreateWindowExA.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function CreateWindowExW.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function TrackPopupMenuEx.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function TrackPopupMenu.
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x7b22a7, 0x850120, {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x73f658, (null), (null), 0x850120): stub
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] init successful!
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  184
  Current serial number in output stream:  184
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] ../common/common.c:183:receiveCommand(): unable to receive data.
```

Comment: Ugh, I am having the same problem on Windows!

Comment: After trying on Windows 7 32 and 64bit and on Mint, it only worked out of the box for me in MacOS :s

Comment: I think there is a newer Tizen IDE version (https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/tizen-sdk) check it out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit picky about the version of xulrunner after installation too

```html
#!/bin/bash
# Proper header for a Bash script.
XURL=http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/2012/03/2012-03-29-03-32-28-mozilla-1.9.2/xulrunner-1.9.2.29pre.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

mkdir /opt/xulrunner
cd /opt/xulrunner
sudo sh -c "wget -O- $XURL | tar -xj"
sudo rm /usr/bin/xulrunner
sudo rm /usr/bin/xpcshell 
sudo ln -s /opt/xulrunner/xulrunner /usr/bin/xulrunner
sudo ln -s /opt/xulrunner/xpcshell /usr/bin/xpcshell 

echo "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla" >> ~/tizen-wearable-sdk/ide/eclipse.ini
echo "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/xulrunner" >> ~/tizen-wearable-sdk/ide/eclipse.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to remove the google talk plugin (in ubuntu)

```
apt-get remove google-talkplugin
```

Answer (score 1):

Few checks

1. Make sure you using the latest JDK (I use 7u65-2.5 )
2. Update the following in /ide/eclipse.ini

> ```
> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=<xulrunner path>
> ```

Worked for me.