# sdb connection Error: timeout

Tags: tizen, tizen-sdb

I'm new to Tizen SDK. After installing, everything was good. I can import an Tizen's example project and run it.
However, I can't create new Tizen project. When I try to create a new project, the SDK crash and give a log file in ${HOME}/tizen-sdk/tools/logs/sdblib-*.log
This is the log:

```
06:17:46 E/DeviceMonitor: sdb connection Error: timeout
06:17:51 E/DeviceMonitor: sdb connection Error: timeout
```

My OS:
Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64Bit

JRE:
Oracle Java version 1.8.0_05

**Update:**

I've just installed the SDK and trying to create a new web app.
Then, it crashed. And i found a log file showed that Error.
I also tried to reinstall the SDK but it's still the same.

Comment: You don't have connection to your device (or emulator); you gave not enough details to tell anything more.

Comment: I haven't done anything, so it's hard to say more. I've updated the details.

Comment: Can you connect to device with sdb using shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDB has not very much to do with it.

Few people reported same problem on Linux platform. Please see this SO question: [Tizen IDE crashes all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158164/tizen-ide-crashes-all-the-time)

Have you tried the latest 2.3 Rev1 version ?